# Set order on displaying paths/images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawing

I have a couple of arcs and rects in a `UIView`, and a `UIImageView` as well. I want to have the `UIImageView` in the background. I have ordered it in IB so that the image view is behind my labels and buttons.

First, I need to put an image in the image view, which I don't want to do in IB. I've tried this code

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"myImage"];
```

But it doesn't work. After I get that working, what can I do to move my paths in front of the image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add image to `UIImageView` :

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: but how do I move the paths in front of it?

Comment: Like I asked in the beginning of the question, I want my drawn paths to be on top of the image. How do I do that?

Comment: u mean u want to put path on imgeView insatnd of @"image.png" ??

Comment: No I want to draw ON the image.png. so that the drawn paths are visible on top of the image

Comment: set myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(25, 20, 200, 200);

Comment: that didn't do anything? That just make a frame doesn't it?

Comment: No. without the imageview i have a three circles (paths). But when I added the imageview, I cant see the circles anymore. The circles (paths) are UNDER the imageview. SO I want to get the paths on top of the imageview

Comment: What is Circle (path) it is UIControl ??

Comment: Sorry u can not add UIimageView to path but you can give shape of imageView as circle

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to draw to put a background image and on top of it want to draw circles(arcs).

If my understanding is correct.  First draw the image on to the view using CGContextDrawImage() and then draw arcs on top of it.  (No need to use image view).